# filter String with empty String in if statement, iOS

Tags: arrays, swift, string, filter

I'm working on a custom keyboard. I'm having trouble filtering Strings Array. I want to filter the array only in `if` statement, I have an array with letters and empty String's. I want to filter Array only in `if` statement because I want to remove last character, not empty String.

Here is my code:

```
keyboardKeyStr = ["h", "e", "l", "l", "o", " ", "", "t", "h", "i", "s", "", "i", "s", " ", "m", "y", " ", "", "a", "r", "r", "a", "y", " "]

if range.length == 1 && text.count == 0 {
    print("Delete Button")

    let emptyStr: String? = ""
    keyboardKeyStr = keyboardKeyStr.filter {$0 != emptyStr}
    keyboardKeyStr.removeLast()
    keyboardKeyArr.append(keyboardView.deleteBtn)
    self.keyboardKeyStr.append("")
}
```

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing. You should add an example array and the expected result. By the way you can replace `text.count == 0` with `text.isEmpty` and `filter {$0 != emptyStr}` with `filter {!$0.isEmpty}` and delete the `let emptyStr` line. And why do you declare `emptyStr` as an optional but assign an non-optional value?? Don't annotate worse types than the compiler can infer.

Comment: I have edited, the array looks like that

Comment: @SandrikaJanjghava You did not include the expected result. (What result are you receiving, and what did you want it to be, and why?)

Answer (score 1):

Try this `keyboardKeyStr = keyboardKeyStr.filter{ $0 != "" && $0 != " "}`

Comment: filter is finding and removing, deleting. I found filterMap and that does great work